# Pandas find index of subarray in array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have arrays

```
a = numpy.array([1,3,5,7])
b = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

Is there a quick command to find all of the matching indices in b that contain a value in a? For example

```
a in b = [0,2,4,6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> np.nonzero(np.in1d(b, a))[0]
array([0, 2, 4, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isin` to find where values exist in an array-like object (also works for list):

```
In [14]:

a = np.array([1,3,5,7])
b = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
# call .index if you are just interested in the index values
b[b.isin(a)].index
Out[14]:
Int64Index([0, 2, 4, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Without accessing the `.index` attribute you get a series returned:

```
In [15]:

b[b.isin(a)]
Out[15]:
0    1
2    3
4    5
6    7
dtype: int64
```